# Locus of centroid given base fixed and vertex moves along a line.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Consider triangle $ABC$ with base $AB$ fixed in length and position. As the vertex $C$ moves on a straight line (which hasn't to be parallel to line $AB$),what is the locus of the centroid of the triangle ?

**My effort:**

After a little bit of playing i see that the locus of the centroid is a line parallel to the base $AB$,but how would i prove it  with means of synthetic geometry .

Comment: In the question stated, you seemed to have the assumption that the line $C$ moves along is parallel to $AB$. It would be better to state it clearly in the question.

Comment: I've taken it as it is written on my book, btw i'm editing now .

Comment: If "the vertex $C$ moves on a straight line (which hasn't to be parallel to line $AB$", then "triangle $ABC$ has always the same area" is not true.

Comment: I see ...I've misinterpreted the problem,how would i prove it then with basic geometry ?

Answer (score 4):

$$ G = \frac{A+B+C}{3} = \frac{A+B}{3}+\frac{C}{3}, $$
hence if $A,B$ stay fixed and $C$ moves on some line $l$, $G$ moves on a line parallel to $l$.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to think about this question.

Let $E$ be the midpoint of side $BC$.

Using Ceva's theorem on $\triangle CDB$ and line $AXE$,

$\frac{CX}{XD}\frac{DA}{AB}\frac{BE}{EC}=1$

$\frac{CX}{XD}=\frac{2}{1}$ (which is a well-known result concerning medians)

Another way this can be stated is: $\frac{CD}{XD}=\frac{3}{1}$

It follows that a scaling of factor $\frac{1}{3}$ with centre $D$ will bring the locus of $C$ to the locus of $X$.

Hence the locus of $X$ is a straight line parallel to the locus of $C$ where the distance from the locus of $X$ to $D$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ the distance from the locus of $C$ to $D$.

Comment: How would i prove it without Ceva's Theorem ?

Comment: Well, we need to get some information about ratio about lengths, so without Ceva's theorem, I don't think this proof can be done. Menelaus' theorem is another related theorem which can fix this gap.

Answer (score 1):

**Geometrical Approach**: 
Let the fixed vertices of $\triangle ABC$ be $A(0, 0)$ (at the origin) & $B(a, 0)$ be lying on the x-axis & the vertex $C(x, b)$ is movable parallel to the base $AB$ say on the line $y=b$

where, $x$ is variable & $a, b$ are arbitrary constants.

then the centroid $G(h, k)$  of $\triangle ABC$ is given as $$(h, k)\equiv\left(\frac{0+a+x}{3}, \frac{0+0+b}{3}\right)\equiv \left(\frac{x+a}{3},\ \frac{b}{3}\right)$$ 
Comparing the corresponding coordinates, we get $h=\frac{x+a}{3}$  & $k=\frac{b}{3}$ which shows that the locus of the centroid $G(h, k)$ is a straight line $\color{red}{y=\frac{b}{3}}$ which is parallel to the fixed base $AB$ i.e. the centriod $G$ moves on a straight line parallel to the fixed base $AB$